# How to convert string to ASCII format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port

I would like to convert regular string to `ASCII format`. This is because I am trying to communicate with the lock controller and it can't only read commands in `ASCII format.`

Below is the code:

```
var port = new SerialPort("COM5", {
  baudRate: 38400
});

    port.on('open', function() {
      port.write('close1', function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
        }
        console.log('message written');
      });
    });
```

Essentially I would like to ensure that close1 communicates in ASCII format instead of the string format.

```
port.write('close1', function(err) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by "ASCII format"? Please [edit] your question to show an example input string and the corresponding output ASCII format.

Comment: Unless your string contains characters that are outside the ASCII character set, you'll communicate in ASCII format.

Comment: What `SerialPort` module are you using? It could matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [this `SerialPort` module](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#module_serialport--SerialPort+write), the `write` function accepts

> Accepts a `Buffer` object, or a type that is accepted by the Buffer constructor (ex. an array of bytes or a string).

When you construct a `Buffer` from a string, you can tell NodeJS what encoding to use; one of the allowed encodings is `ascii` (the default is `utf-8` which is ASCII for characters 32-127).

So:

```
// NodeJS v4 and earlier
port.write(new Buffer('close1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
  }
  console.log('message written');
});
```

As of v6, we're supposed to use `Buffer.from` instead:

```
// NodeJS v6 and later
port.write(Buffer.from('close1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
  }
  console.log('message written');
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Lets say I wanted to listen to the command response how would i log that into console? For instance if i send it a command status1, or status2, it should return open/close.

Comment: @John: If you're using the one I linked above, you'd listen for the `data` event (according to the docs; I haven't used it).

Comment: hence console.log(data)? right after console.log(message written)

Comment: @John: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that. You'd *listen* for the `data` event, see the examples of that in the linked documentation.

Comment: sorry I am little bit slow. I simply mean to console.log the response of the command written.  Are you refering to the readline parser for that https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#event-data   https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#serialportparsers--object

Comment: @John: I'm referring to that event, yes. Again, I haven't used the lib. If you want lines of data, then yes, using the `readline` parser sounds right.

Comment: thanks would i then do console.log(parser) to be able to read the response on console.

Comment: @John: Again, I've never used that library. If you need help using that library, I suggest posting a question with your best attempt at using it and asking for help from people who have.